# Unable to annotate multiple lines in Brat

Tags: nlp, brat

When I am trying to annotate multiple lines in Brat, it throws me the following error:

[image]

What does this error trace mean/say? Also, is this is an expected behavior?

How does one annotate multiple lines in Brat?

Comment: You have not provided a [mcve] so I cannot be sure, but it is likely you are running an old version of brat, and crashing into one of the fixed bugs. Try to get brat directly by github clone; use `python2` branch for Python 2, or `master` for Python 3. However, note that brat was not originally designed to mark multi-line spans, and will join the lines in visualisation.

Comment: @Amadan I am currently running v1.3 itself, which happens to be the latest version.  When trying to annotate multiple lines, it either throws me the above error, or collapses into a tiny span whose text is not visible

Comment: 1.3 is the latest _packaged_ version. We did a lot of improvements and bugfixes that never got into that package, so that the only way (for now) to get the latest version is by `git clone` (not github clone, lol, that's a typo). We are considering releasing an updated package sometime later this year, since it's been abominably long. Suffice it to say, I cannot reproduce your error on my end.

Comment: @Amadan Added the test file here: https://github.com/nlplab/brat/issues/1285

Comment: Tested with test file. You can find the result at the same location.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot on Brat v 1.3. But here is a possible workaround, for occasional use. Replace the period in the text by a character which is not in the [list of special characters understood by Brat](https://github.com/nlplab/brat/blob/e3c5d4fad557bb49b0a1a106962709d172e5a3d9/tools/conll09tostandoff.py#L37).
I use myself the [interpunct (middot)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot#Typography):

`·`

This is a second best for sure, but it works. I also tried the '[combining dot below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(diacritic))' on a space or on a period on one of Brat's demo files, but Brat does not accept it (maybe because it's a "long" UTF-8 character?). If you don't care much about changing the text, then ";" and ":" work too.

Answer (score 0):

There may be permission/ access problem in your data or work folder. you may try putting your data into the data/example folder